# Where is the rest of the response time coming from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running a local copy of the railscasts website to get familiar with rails 3. I was examining the development log after I was clicking around, and here's what I see:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-16 14:17:07 -0500
  Processing by EpisodesController#index as HTML
  Episode Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "episodes".* FROM "episodes" WHERE (published_at <= '2010-12-16 19:17:07.872204') ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
Rendered shared/_navigation.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Sponsor Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sponsors".* FROM "sponsors" WHERE (active = 't')
  Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" ORDER BY name
Rendered shared/_side.html.erb (4.2ms)
Rendered episodes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 117ms (Views: 12.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
```

Where is the rest of the response time coming from? It says 117ms for the full request and it looks like it's logging all database queries. Is the remaining time really just controller logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was simple. This is a development log snippet, so all of that extra time was gobbled up by rails reloading the classes.

Answer (score 1):

The rest of the time would go to:

- Controller, view, model logic
- Sending/receiving the HTTP data
- Rails internals
- Logging, printing the console

Comment: What is the distinction between model logic and ActiveRecord time?

Also isn't view time accounted for